# Rails - dynamically change options in forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for

I currently have a form that creates `clinicians`.  On this form I would like to have a dropdown for `clinician_type`where a user can select between `physician`, `nurse`, and `other`.  Depending on the user's selection the form would adapt to either allow them to select a `Speciality` for a `physician` or an `Occupation` for a `nurse`.

I tried to implement the answer to [23459948](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459948/how-do-i-create-a-auto-adaptive-form) and adapt it to having three options but I don't know javascript and I can't get it to work.

`Clinician` `belongs_to` `:occupation` and `:speciality` and `Occupation` and `Speciality` each `has_many` `:clinicians`.

My code to implement this in the form looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for @clinician do |form| %>
      Type of new clinician: <select id="clinician_type">
          <option value="physician">Physician</option>
          <option value="nurse">Nurse</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select><br />

      <span id="webname">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :speciality_id %>
          <%= form.collection_select :speciality_id, Speciality.all, :id, :name, { include_blank: true }, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </span>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("clinician_type").onchange = function () {
            if (document.getElementById("clinician_type").options[document.getElementById("clinician_type").selectedIndex].value == "physician")
                document.getElementById("webname").style.display = "block";
            else
                document.getElementById("webname").style.display = "none";
        }
      </script>

      <span id="webname2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :occupation_id %>
          <%= form.collection_select :occupation_id, Occupation.all, :id, :name, { include_blank: true }, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </span>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("clinician_type").onchange = function () {
            if (document.getElementById("clinician_type").options[document.getElementById("clinician_type").selectedIndex].value == "nurse")
                document.getElementById("webname2").style.display = "block";
            else
                document.getElementById("webname2").style.display = "none";
        }
      </script>
```

Followed by many more options that are the same for both `physicians` and `nurses`.

Currently `Speciality` shows up for all options and `Occupation` appears only when `nurse` is selected (as it is supposed to).

I would really appreciate any advise for making a form that adapts depending on a dropdown selection.  I've tried implementing the answer to [17525724](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525724/rails-dynamically-changing-form-content) but haven't gotten it to work either.

Comment: What exactly is your roadblock currently? The other drop downs don't show? Rails error?JS error?

Comment: Your problem is tied to the front-end logic. That's because once the page is served from the server, it's only plain text HTML/CSS. So, what would I do in this situation?, I would render every `form`  in one view and with the help of JavaScript i'll do the logic for every scenario.  `knockout.js`  excels in this kind of problems. In the following link there is an example that solves this problem http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: Currently `Speciality` shows up for all options and `Occupation` appears only when `nurse` is selected (as it is supposed to)

Comment: @yeyo I can't get `knockout.js` to work.  I have `          <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: displayMessage" /> Display message</label>
 
          <div data-bind="if: displayMessage">Here is a message. Astonishing.</div>

          <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.3.0.js'>

          ko.applyBindings({
              displayMessage: ko.observable(false)
          });

          </script>` and I have `knockout-3.3.0.js` added to my assets and `application.js` but there is no functionality

Comment: @Skiapex I would recommend you to replicate the examples of knockout's page in a separate folder/files, so you can contemplate if it suits your needs, before working with rails. That said, check what your browser's console says, something may be wrong. For instance, if you're using rails, then this line of code  `<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.3.0.js'>` may be the cause of the problem, because that's not the way you normally load an asset served from Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just refer this [railscast episode #88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) they have built dynamic select menus starting from scratch!

Or better watch this [revised #88 episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1zZ4Lgzf9s) on Youtube.

Follow the steps.You will get it.